# How to go the default alarm sounds from my application in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have using alarm button for remind something. my question is how to go the default iphone alarm sounds when i click the alarm button in my app.any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access default alarm app in iPhone without Jailbreaking.

Comment: jailbreaking means..can u explain